# In reviewboard add local repository error "Permission denied accessing the local Git repository ......"

Tags: git, permission-denied, review-board

I need help now!

**Environment**：Centos 6.7 + reviewboard 2.5.1.1

Now I have installed reviewboard in **/var/www/reviewboard**,the website user and group is apache:apache,

in the web page,I fill in like this：

`Hosting service:custom`

```
Repository Type:Git

Path:/home/jxd/Git/monitor/.git

Mirror Path: git@git.company.com:company/monitor
```

current user：jxd

project ：monitor

Then I try to save these configuration，but web page says **“Permission denied accessing the local Git repository '/home/jxd/Git/monitor/.git'”**

and I have tried to execute following command:

`chown o+w /home/jxd/Git/monitor/.git`

but it doesn't work.

So,please tell me where is wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `sudo su` and running these commands?

Comment: yes,I execute `sudo -i ` to switch root user,then `rb-site install /var/www/reviewboard`. In the end,`chown -R apache:apache /var/www/reviewboard`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you tell me what to do next?

Comment: Can you find out under which user is your Git running?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You means local Git repository's user and group, It's `jxd:jxd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just my guesses, which are too long to be a comment but not a complete answer:

1. check under which accound your *HTTP server* works. I guess in Centos6 it would be something like `apache` for `apache` web server, `nginx` for `nginx` server etc.
2. You've placed your repository into user's HOME folder. Likely, the web-server user from the p.1 doesn't have access to the whole user folder (`/home/jxd`), no matter what permisssions are set for a subdirectory inside that folder.
3. Usually shared resources should be placed into a "common folders", like `/srv/www` or `/var/www`, `/var/lib/www`... In any case make sure that the web-server user has appropriate rights for accessing the repo (reading and maybe writing).
4. You may find useful to create a new group designated for the users  of the particular repo (all users, including web-server user) and create a "shared" repo (use `git init --shared=group` with subsequent `chown -R :<designated_group> /path/to/repo.git`)

Comment: **OK,It works**,thanks everyone. I don't change the local git repository's user and group, I just move the local git repository out of my user's HOME folder，then I move it to `/var/www/` folder,I try to add Path again, unexceptedly,it works .I think it confirms your second reason you said.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add another answer here. ReviewBoard gives a permission denied error **when working with treeless repos**. It seems to require a full checkout before it will work.

If you have just the .git directory, make a clone from it and point ReviewBoard there.